DDEV: Configure auto completion for symfony based CLI tools ( fe magento )
I am trying to configure auto completion for magento CLI tool in DDEV web container.
For autocompletion I use the package: bamarni/symfony-console-autocomplete.
The package configuration (.ddev/homeadditions/.bashrc.d/autocomplete):
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/composer/vendor/bin"
eval "$(symfony-autocomplete)"


and composer packages (.ddev/web-build/Dockerfile):
ENV COMPOSER_HOME="/usr/local/composer"
ENV SHELL="bash"
RUN composer global require consolidation/cgr
RUN $COMPOSER_HOME/vendor/bin/cgr  bamarni/symfony-console-autocomplete
ENV COMPOSER_HOME=""


And when I try:
ddev ssh
magento <TAB>

I got:  magento bash: _get_comp_words_by_ref: command not found
Any ideas advises ?


magento bash: _get_comp_words_by_ref: command not found

bash-completion is not installed by default in the ddev-webserver container.
It can be added manually with:
ddev config --webimage-extra-packages bash-completion


thanks! It works.
Do you know if it possible to enable completion directly on host, like:
ddev magento <TAB> ?

Take a look at ~/.ddev/commands/web/autocomplete/, these are the autocompletion scripts that we have. So you can research how to add something else there. Also you can look inside DDEV PRs to see how autocompletion was added for commands like npm.
